# Getting: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::serialize() must return a string or NULL

Tags: symfony

I added a couple of fields in my `Entity1` file like:

```
/**
     * @var integer $typeid
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="typeid", type="integer")
     */
    private $typeid;
```

And added getter and setter method for it.

In my controller I am fetching data using:

```
$result = $entityManager->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity1')
->findby(array('year' => $year));
```

I send my result to the twig file in an array with name `'entities'` (say)
In my twig file I loop through all the entities in the array and display the
data.

I am getting two exceptions:

```
1/2
ErrorException: Notice: serialize(): "id" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/DataCollector.php line 29

2/2
Exception: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::serialize() must return a string or NULL
```

I am new to Symfony 2, and am not sure whats happening. I am guessing that the new fields
that I added in the Entity file is causing some problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error when add to my Product entity this code:

```
/**
 * @var Type $type
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product\Type")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $type;
```

Here my template:

```
{% render "StoreBundle:Product:list" with { 'products': products } %}
```

But if I change template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

... or change hydration mode to array:

```
$products = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('StoreBundle:Product')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

... error does not occur